# Pre-trained Weight Initialization Problem with Skip Connections in Keras

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to implement pre-trained VGG-16 for weight initializing along with Skip Connections. Although model's summary shows correct number of parameters, but weights are not initialized properly. My code is given below:

```
vgg16_model = applications.vgg16.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False,input_shape = (224, 224, 3) )
L1 = vgg16_model.get_layer('block1_conv1').output
L3 = vgg16_model.get_layer('block2_conv1').output
L5 = vgg16_model.get_layer('block3_conv1').output
L6 = vgg16_model.get_layer('block3_conv2').output
L8 = vgg16_model.get_layer('block4_conv1').output
L9 = vgg16_model.get_layer('block4_conv2').output
L11 = vgg16_model.get_layer('block5_conv1').output
L12 = vgg16_model.get_layer('block5_conv2').output
L13= vgg16_model.get_layer('block5_pool').output
skipConnectionLayers = Concatenate()([L1,L3,L5,L6,L8,L9,L11,L12])
x = Flatten(name='flatten_1')(L13)
x = Concatenate()([skipConnectionLayers, x]) #weights are initialized propery if this line is commented
x = Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='fc4')(x)
my_model = Model(input=vgg16_model.input, output=x)
```

In my opinion, as I am setting include_top = False and making changes in deeper layers, weight initialization should work fine.

Thanks,

Comment: What evidence you have that weight initialization is not working properly?

Comment: Initial loss value is too high (which is not the case if I do not use skip connections). Further, loss is not decreased anymore after first epoch.

Comment: That could be an issue produced by the skip connections themselves, as VGG is not normally trained that way.

Comment: True, without skip connections weight initialization works fine. I actually want to use skip connections along with VGG to check if results are improved or not.

Comment: I think you have to train a VGG from scratch for that to work, its too different from the normal VGG.